# Yacc recursion method for echoing a list?

Tags: bison, yacc, jison

I am struggling to understand yacc recursion.  So I created a minimal language that I want to simply echo a list of number given to it.  I am using JISON.  Here is the JISON:

```
/* description: Parses end executes mathematical expressions. */

/* lexical grammar */
%lex
%%

\s+                   /* skip whitespace */
[0-9]+("."[0-9]+)?\b  return 'NUMBER'
<<EOF>>               return 'EOF'
.                     return 'INVALID'

/lex

%start expressions

%% /* language grammar */

expressions
    : e EOF 
        {}
    ;

 e
    : NUMBER {}
    | NUMBER e
 ;
```

What actions do I need to echo the list of numbers separated by blanks?

Comment: To start with you should set the number you scan so the parser can read it. With Lex/Yacc this is typically done by using `yylval`. Then just add code to the parser-rules to print the number.

Comment: You should use left recursion in Yacc, not right recursion.

Answer (score 0):

@JoachimPileborg was correct when he said:

> To start with you should set the number you scan so the parser can read it. With Lex/Yacc this is typically done by using `yylval`. Then just add code to the parser-rules to print the number.

JISON uses the grammar processor of yacc/bison but the actions must be specified in Javascript. As you are wanting an example of actions, I am assuming  you can program in Javascript?

```
/* description: Parses end executes mathematical expressions. */

/* lexical grammar */
%lex
%%

\s+                   /* skip whitespace */
[0-9]+("."[0-9]+)?\b  yylval = ParseInt(yytext); return 'NUMBER'
<<EOF>>               return 'EOF'
.                     return 'INVALID'

/lex

%start expressions

%% /* language grammar */

expressions
    : e EOF 
        {}
    ;

 e
    : NUMBER { print($1); }
    | NUMBER e { print($1); }
 ;
```

All I've done is convert the lexeme for the number into an integer and stored it in `yylval` in the lexical part, and printed that value in the parser part whenever a `NUMBER` token is used.

Hopefully, that will make it clear. (PS - I've not run and tested it, not having JISON)